# How can an atom be in an ensemble of energy states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

So I was reading this [pdf](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/pls/portallive/docs/1/55905.PDF)
and in sections 3.2.3 it states theres is an atom with |$\psi_{o}\rangle$ which is a linear combination of two energy eigenstates (a ground |0$\rangle$ and excited state |1$\rangle$ the atom is a two level atom). How can this be? How can atom occupy both energy states? This document is jus reviewing basic quantum mechanics concepts for the purpose of delivering the concepts of information theory. 
Is it a correct view to take that the finite probability of an atom to occupy both ground and excited states is a result of the information we posses about the atom? Or is this superposition an actual physical phenomenon, rather than one of information uncertainty?

Comment: Please include anything from that link that is needed for the question. If you're just asking what it means for an atom to be in state $|E_0\rangle + |E_1 \rangle$ then the link isn't really needed anyway.

Comment: Boltzmann distribution would be described by a mixed state, so a probability distribution over pure states where the atom is in one of the possible energy eigenstates. That's different from a pure state where the atom is in a well defined superposition of the energy eigenstates. So, it's similar to the difference between a probability distribution over the vectors (0,1) and (1,0) and the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1,1)$. The fact that such vectors can represent physical states suggesting that the atom is in different states at the same time is what makes QM difficult to understand intuitively.

Comment: edited added a few more details

Answer (score 0):

Your question is the most basic concept of quantum mechanics. Classically what you are thinking is right but when you have a quantum system it can occupy as many quantum states as possible. There is a certain probability that the system will be in certain state. The quantum state is destroyed if you make a measurement and you will then get a definitive end result. There are several experiments performed to prove this.

One such experiment was ultra low intensity Michelson Morley experiment. The light was so weak that only one photon is inside the whole setup. The probability wave associated with that photon splits into two waves i.e. the photon is quantum in one of the two possible quantum paths, they recombine interfere back (i.e. the photon interfere with itself). This experiment indeed gives the correct interference pattern when exposed for long enough time.

You may go through some very interesting texts like Lectures on Physics by R. P. Feynman (Part III).